# Does the damage from Slow Times rune 'Time Warp' stack with multiple Slow times?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

In Diablo 3, if an enemy is in 2 or 3 overlapping Slow Times, will the 15% damage taken increase rune stack to 30% or 45%? Or are the mobs only experiencing 1 debuff to increase their damage taken by 15%?

Comment: 1. You could test it easily yourself 2. Very probably not, because it would be kinda too op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the increase in damage is capped at 15% for this skill. You can not add this effect on top of itself.